# Eclipse: How to ignore .git subdir when adding one project to another project's build path?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I'm developing an application that is supposed to run on both Android as well as regular Java SE.

I have an eclipse project called **foobar-core** which contains code that is used both by the Android and the SE version. I have another project called **foobar-android**, which contains all android-specific code.

I need to reference some of the **foobar-core** code in the **foobar-android** project, so I added **foobar-core** to **foobar-android** in Settings -> Java Build path -> Projects -> Required projects on the build path. This works fine, as I can use code from **foobare-core** in **foobar-android** now.

Here's the problem: Both **foobar-core** and **foobar-android** are independent git repositories, which means they both have a .git subdirectory. Now I get a lot of warnings on the "Console" tab whenever I compile **foobar-android**. They look like this:

```
/foobar-core/src/.git/HEAD conflicts with another file already put at .git/HEAD
/foobar-core/src/.git/config conflicts with another file already put at .git/config
/foobar-core/src/.git/description conflicts with another file already put at > .git/description
/foobar-core/src/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample conflicts with another file already > put at .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
```

How can I tell Eclipse to ignore the .git files when importing sources from the foobar-core project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you just have a single git repo, it is good to ignore the .git directory because other Eclipse will waste a lot of time looking at the files in it even though it never needs to do anything with them. In particular, when you do a project wide search, Eclipse will search through the all the files in .git directory, which takes a long time and ends up showing you lots of duplicates (or almost duplicates, older versions of the same file with the same search term found).

I think the Eclipse git extensions probably take care of this but if you don't want to install yet another extension, the best way I have found it to tell Eclipse that all .git directories are "Derived", which seems to make Eclipse somewhat ignore the contained files.

You do this by switching from the Package Explorer view to the Navigator view, where you should see the .git folder. Right-click on the .git folder, selecting properties, selecting Resource from the settings selector, and then checking the "Derived" box.

Comment: Thanks, this actually answers the question, unlike the 'answer' above that suggests using .gitignore.

Comment: Yeah I got a kick out of that 'answer' as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a `.gitignore` file that simply ignored the entire `foobar-code` project.

Comment: Maybe my problem explanation wasn't good enough: The error doesn't occur when committing to git, but when I *compile* the project in Eclipse. This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/PuCbH.png

Comment: @rodion: That's interesting, I would still try the gitignore file though.

Comment: Haha! Josh K, you are hilarious!